# Something went wrong in my login:

Tags: 18.04

First, I don't know how, the normal login does not appear. Instead it says: "**Welcome to kor**", then below that it's written Login where I am suppose to enter my username. Then password.

After that, another authentication appears, which says,"**Enter password to unlock your login.... The login keyring did not get unlocked when you logged into your computer.**" Where I have to enter my password and press unlock.

Other changes are:

- the terminal was changed from black to white, with no minimize/maximize button;
- almost all the system apps are missing minimize/maximize button.

So what is going on!?

Comment: What is the last change you made to your system?

Comment: I installed uGet, xdm download manager, then to do that updated t-tujikawa/ppa. Also I updated something from sofetware and update, which i did not pay much attention. Before that everything was going alright.

Comment: Also repository from ppa:noobslab/apps

Comment: Try to investigate in how to change theme for your desktop manager.

Comment: That  t-tujikawa/ppa doesn't have a bionic version. Are you really running 18.04?

Comment: yes, I am running ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: 2020-01-07 21:27:37 install libeb16:amd64 <none> 4.4.3-12
2020-01-07 21:27:38 install libopencc2-data:all <none> 1.0.4-5
2020-01-07 21:27:39 install libopencc2:amd64 <none> 1.0.4-5
2020-01-07 21:27:40 install libqt5sql5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4
2020-01-07 21:27:41 install libqt5help5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
2020-01-07 21:27:41 install libqt5x11extras5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
2020-01-07 21:27:42 install goldendict:amd64 <none> 1.5.0~rc2+git20170908+ds-1
2020-01-07 21:27:44 install libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4

Comment: 2020-01-08 07:13:18 install uget:amd64 <none> 2.2.0-1build1
2020-01-08 07:14:02 install xdm:amd64 <none> 1:1.1.11-3ubuntu1
These are the recent activities.